# AngularJS with Google Chart drawing error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use AngularJS 1.2. I need to add google charts on my html page. I use page navigation with angular `ngRoute`  . When I add google chart on the first page, it worked, but when I add the google charts on a seperate page and load it with ngRoute, it gives error in console

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

this is how I import google charts js,
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>`

This is how I call google chart. this was taken from a tutorial.

```
<body>
            <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function drawChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Time', 'get', 'add'],
            ['2004',  1000,      400],
            ['2005',  1170,      460],
            ['2006',  660,       1120],
            ['2007',  1030,      540]
          ]);

          var options = {
            title: 'Cache Statues'
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

          chart.draw(data, options);
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    </script>
    </body>
```

Any one let me know how I can fix this ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/528 this should help

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything. Thanks, but I wrote the javascript adding, throught getScript(), issue still there..